# Get functions' previous return statement

Tags: python

Not quite sure how to ask this but let me just explain.

```
import random
import string.ascii_uppercase

chars = string.as
def random_string():
   return "".join([random.choice(chars) + " " for i in range(10])

print(random_string())
f = open("test.txt", "a+")
f.write(random_string())
f.close()
```

in my example `print` and `f.write` will both perform an operation with a different string, how can I make it so `f.write` writes the same string as gets printed, and then when `print` gets called again it creates a new string and `f.write` follows.

Comment: I see zero return statements here.

Comment: Use a variable.

Comment: Do you mean you would like to save the result, e.g. `result = random_string()`?

Comment: Yes I'd like the same result and sorry for the no return statement, I wrote this code in the browser to simplify the question, edited it.